# How to send content and file as Multipart Form Data from Java using org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart?

Tags: java, forms, rest, dropwizard

I want to send an HTTP post with one form parameter as File and Another one which sends a list of numbers.

Request:

`curl -X POST \
  http://127.0.0.1:5001/verify \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----
  -F 'items=["Apple", "Orange"]' \
  -F 'photo=@/home/.../img.jpg'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
        .build();

MultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart()
        .field("items", "[\"Apple\", \"Orang\"]", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
        .bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("photo", new File("img.png"));

Response response = client
        .target(url)
        .request()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache")
        .post(Entity.entity(multiPart), multiPart.getMediaType());
```

For this to work, you need to add the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You tagged [dropwizard](/questions/tagged/dropwizard), so I assume you are already using/have Jersey client. If you don't then add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

---

#### See also

- [Jersey Client Docs](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html)
- [Jersey MultiPart Docs](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart)